# If $|A_n \cap C| \to |B \cap C|$ for all $C$, is $B$ the limit of $A_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of subsets of $[0,1]$. If there exists a set $B$ such that $|A_n \cap C| \to |B \cap C|$ as $n \to \infty$ for all measurable $C \subset [0,1]$, is it true that $\lim_n A_n = B$, or perhaps that $|A_n \Delta B| \to 0$, where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference?

I have come across this particular situation while toying around with a problem ... I do not have enough expertise to even have a guess at what could be going on here.

Thank you in advance for any answers!

Comment: Sorry, what is $\lim_n A_n$? How do you define limit of a sequence of sets?

Comment: I'm thinking naively of a pointwise limit of indicator functions of the sets. If that's confusing in the original question I can just delete it; showing $|A_n \Delta B| \to 0$ would be enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assume such $B$ exists. Now, $|A_n \Delta B| = |(A_n - B) \cup (B - A_n)| = |A_n - B| + |B - A_n|$ (because they're disjoint). It's enough to show that each of these summands goes to 0.

For $|B - A_n|$, take $C = B$ in your condition. Then, $|A_n \cap B| \to |B \cap B| = |B|$. Now, $|B| = |(B - A_n) \cup (A_n \cap B)| = |B-A_n| + |A_n \cap B|$, so $|B - A_n| = |B| - |A_n \cap B| \to 0$.

To show that $|A_n - B| \to 0$, take $C = \bigcup A_n - B$. Then $|A_n \cap C| = |A_n \cap (\bigcup A_n - B)| = |A_n - B|$, but, by assumption, $|A_n \cap C| \to |B \cap C| = |B \cap (\bigcup A_n - B)| = |\emptyset| = 0$.

Comment: `\triangle` produces $\triangle$, which is probably better for the symmetric difference than `\Delta` (both typographically and spacing-wise). If you want to use Delta, you should use `\mathop{\Delta}` to ensure MathJax gives the proper spacing: compare `A_n\Delta B` ($A_n\Delta B$) vs `A_n\mathop{\Delta}B` ($A_n\mathop{\Delta}B$).  $\LaTeX$ has `\vartriangle`, but I don't know if MathJax supports it; let's see: $\vartriangle$. So that could also work.